# create an button on desktop

Tags: c++, python, windows, api

I've collected many nice wall papers over years. 
I know python and c++ (a little MFC eperience).
I want to make a programme that can change my wallpapers.

I want to operate like this:
     there is a little icon (half transparent), if i click it, it change my wallpapers to the next picture in my wallpaper collection folder.

I found many infos of changing wallpaper by programme by google.
But can't find out the win7 API for adding a button on desktop.

Please some one tell me how to set a icon-button on the desktop, or it's just there's no such API?

EDIT:
    I just find that there are ways to make a window unmovable. So, I think now I need to find ways to make windows out of an icon. Then it'll looks like a button on desktop. And, there are ways to make windows taking some response when it's clicked(once), right?

Closure:
    Captain's method may be a better way for people with good understanding of windows. 
    I know python, but few knowledge of MFC or similar framework with deep relations with the OS itself. This desktop button creation is very hard to implement for me. 
    Modifying christian's script and a windows shortcut would be a not-good-looking compromise. I'll do it this way.

Comment: Putting it on the desktop might not be a good idea since it can easily be obscured by app windows. I suggest putting it in the system tray for easier access.

Comment: I want one-click only, on system tray, I guess I'll have to click the tray icon to pop out something and click again.  So, I hope I can add a button on the desktop,, since I'm only changing the wall paper, I feel a button on desktop feels a good extension for windows. I change wallpaper quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a python program that saves my school grades as my background

a snippet that might be helpful is;

```
pathToBmp = "imagename or image directory"
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20  
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pathToBmp ,
                                      0)
```

this will change you're desktop BG to whatever file-name you but in the `pathToBmp`

I'm sure you can figure the rest out pretty easily

and instead of a button maybe make a shortcut that runs the python program that switches the BG to the next pic

i don't know if that's what you were looking for but just some pointers and ideas :)

EDIT:
Maybe this will be helpful to you

[Windows 7 Gadget Tutorial](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/A_2000-Create-a-Win7-Gadget.html)
[Windows Sidebar Object Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965853.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Christian, your method works good. But what I really want is a way (or a windows API) for adding a button on desktop. But If I can't find out how to do that, your suggestion would be a very nice way to do it.

Comment: I just googled something, it's the windows shortcut, using the shortcut to run your python script would be easy. But it'll not look nice and it's not a button, either.

Comment: Thats true, but do you want the button on your desktop or like somewhere else ?

Comment: on my desktop, I just find some new things, and added them in my question(EDIT part). Actually, I hope the button looks just like one part of the desktop. I once thought it's quite easy,, but it's not

Comment: the only thing i can think off is adding a program to the quick launch , task-bar or the system tray otherwise i cant find anything i cant experiment because im not running 7

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no straight forward way to add a button to the desktop without jumping through a lot of hoops. You can create a child control  and set the parent window to the desktop but you will not receive button click notifications. This is because they are sent only to the parent window of the control. The closest and easiest solution for making a control *appear* on the desktop is to create it and set it's z-order to bottom most by calling [`SetWindowPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your application will still be able to receive button notification messages but the control always appear behind all other windows. You may need to override the behavior of minimize and maximize messages though since the desktop can minimize all windows.

You also have the option of adding an icon on the system tray with [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The system tray will send messages to a window you specify any time you click on the icon. The small example below shows how to add the icon to the system tray.

```
static const UINT WM_TRAYMESSAGE = WM_USER + 1000;
static const UINT IDC_TRAYICON = 100l;

NOTIFYICONDATA nid;

//Tray Class Stuff
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hwnd; // Window to receive notifications
nid.uID = 100; // Id sent to window on button clicks
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON|NIF_MESSAGE;
nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDC_TRAYICON);
nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAYMESSAGE; // notification to send to window

// Add the tray icon
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

Any time a user clicks on the icon the window you specify will receive the `WM_TRAYMESSAGE` message. The value of `uID` and other information is also passed as parameters to the window allowing you to identify which icon was clicked (in the event multiple icons are added).

Comment: Thanks Captain. But I want to put the button on the desktop so that it may need one less click to act

Comment: You do know you can configure the system tray to always show the icon? That reduces the steps to use to a single click.

Comment: I don't quite know how to operate on system tray. But I want the icon on desktop because it feels natural, 'a button on desktop used for changing desktop icon', I just suddenly got on fire to make this come true.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have said "I want one-click only, on system tray" in reply to my original comment.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. I actually thought all system tray can do is pop out a window before your reply. Thanks for your info

Comment: No, the windows that pop up from a tray icon are created by the application that owns the icon except for the pull out panel containing hidden icons. Once you click on the tray icon you get a notification message that you can do whatever you want with. Show a window, change the wallpaper, or do nothing. I've also added an additional solution for changing the z-order of the button.

Answer (score -1):

There is an easiest way.
Install VBest Icon groups. ( it is a desktop icon stack )
Then select any stack and add a single button. ( drag and drop any application will get its link and icon in the stack )
Select the stack and in its settings, set transparency equals 0 ( slide to left)
That is it. Now you have a single button with link.